# Expectation of quotient of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $X_1,...X_n$ be independent, identically distributed and nonnegative random variables, and let $k\le n$. Compute: $$E\left[{\sum_{i=1}^k X_i\over \sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\right].$$ This question has already been asked: [Expectation of random variables ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852890/expectation-of-random-variables-ratio).

The thing is that my teacher told me that the solution in the link wasn't really a "solution" the correct thing to do is to compute the conditional expectation of $${\sum_{i=1}^k X_i\over \sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$$ given that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=m$ where $m$ is a positive integer, but I have no idea how to do this, I would really appreciate if you can help me with this problem.

Comment: I know it's been a year and a half, but I suspect your professor was wrong that the solution without conditioning is inadequate. I asked a followup: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136004/expectation-of-ratio-of-sums-of-i-i-d-random-variables-whats-wrong-with-the-s

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can prove as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E \Big[ \frac{\sum _{i=1}^k X_i}{\sum _{i=1}^n X_i} \Big]
&  =
\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \mathsf E \Big[ \frac{\sum _{i=1}^k X_i}{\sum _{i=1}^n X_i} \mid {\sum _{i=1}^n X_i}=m\Big]\mathsf P({\sum _{i=1}^n X_i}=m)
\\[1ex] & = 
\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \mathsf E \Big[ \frac{\sum _{i=1}^k X_i}{m} \mid {\sum _{i=1}^n X_i}=m\Big]\mathsf P({\sum _{i=1}^n X_i}=m)
\\[1ex] & = 
\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m} \sum _{i=1}^{k}\mathsf E \Big[ X_i \mid {\sum _{i=1}^n X_i}=m\Big]\mathsf P({\sum _{i=1}^n X_i}=m)
\\[1ex] & = 
\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m} \frac{km}{n} \mathsf P({\sum _{i=1}^n X_i}=m)
\\[1ex] & = \frac{k}{n} \sum _{m=0}^{\infty}\mathsf P({\sum _{i=1}^n X_i}=m)
\\[1ex] & = \frac{k}{n}
\end{align}$$
**Note:** I have used identical distribution of $X_i$s and this fact that $E \Big[ {\sum _{i=1}^n X_i} \mid {\sum _{i=1}^n X_i}=m\Big] = m$ to conclude that $E \Big[ X_i \mid {\sum _{i=1}^n X_i}=m\Big]= \frac{m}{n}$.

Comment: Note: In fact we do not need $X_i$s to be independent. Identical distribution is enough.

Comment: Actually, $X_i$'s independence is necessary.  The $X_i$'s being i.i.d. allows you to prove the $X_i/\Sigma$ being i.d. (but no longer independent).  Basically I think what you said in the Note is wrong.  See my counter-example at the 2nd half of [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3372491/expectation-of-random-variables-ratio-with-positive-weights/3372766#3372766)

Comment: @antkam I agree. Thanks for your counter example.

Answer (score 8):

$\begin{align}
\text{Let }\qquad M &=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i & \text{Define a new random variable}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^k X_i / \sum_{i=1}^n X_i)
 & = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^k X_i / M\mid M)) & \text{Law of Iterated Expectation}
\\[1ex]
 & = \mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^k \mathsf E(X_i/M\mid M)) & \text{Linearity of Expectation}
\\[1ex]
 & = \mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^k 1/n) & \{X_i\}\sim\text{ i.i.d.}
\\[1ex]
 & = k/n
\end{align}$

Comment: How exactly does the Xi's being iid justify the penultimate step?

Comment: @BCLC **identical** means that $ \mathsf E(X_i/M \mid M)=\mathsf E(X_1/M \mid M)$ for all $i\in\{1..n\}$ and so $n \mathsf E(X_1/M\mid M) = \mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i/\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \mid \sum_{i=1}^n X_i) = 1$, thus...

Comment: Elegant! But should there be an almost surely there? $E(M/M | M) = M/M E( 1 | M) = M/M = 1$ a.s.? Like if X is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable, $E[X | \mathscr{G}] = X$ a.s.?