# Expected value : Reciprocal Sum Positive iid Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be iid positive valued random variables. Show that $\mathbb{E}[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}]=\frac{m}{n}$ for $1\leq m\leq n$.

I know $\mathbb{E}[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}]=m \mathbb{E}[\frac{X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}]$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420091/find-expectation-of-fracx-1-cdots-x-mx-1-cdots-x-n-when-x-1-l/, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258485/expectation-of-quotient-of-random-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852890/expectation-of-random-variables-ratio?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can prove that $\mathbb{E}[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}]=m \mathbb{E}[\frac{X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}]$, then simply find $$1=\mathbb{E}[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}]=n \mathbb{E}[\frac{X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}]$$ and conclude.

Comment: Proving the first part is not difficult, as $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$ is a linear operator. Impressive, I thought it would be some sort of induction and/or make use of the fact that $X_i >0$ but this looks okay.

Comment: Linearity is not enough. Are you shure that you can prove that all fractions $\frac{X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$ has the same expectation (or even the same distribution)?

Comment: Yes, won't that be because of symmetry? The $X_i$ are iid and the denominator stays the same.

Comment: Yes, this is effect of symmetry, which is possible due to independence too. Two vectors $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ and $(X_2,X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ have the same joint distribution since it is a product of marginals and the order of multiplication does not matter. Then any function of first vector has the same distribution as the same function of the second vector. This implies that two fractions $\frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$ and $\frac{X_2}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$ are identically distributed.