# Expectation of $\frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+...+X_{k}}{X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+...+X_{n}}$ , $1 \leq k \leq n$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Prove the following statement:

> Let $X_{1},X_{2}, \dots ,X_{n}$ be a set of exchangeable random variables. Then, $$E\left(\frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+\dots +X_{k}}{X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+\dots +X_{n}}\right) = \frac{k}{n}  , \qquad 1 \leq k \leq n. $$

I tried writing $\frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+...+X_{k}}{X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+...+X_{n}}$ 
in a nice form so that I can make calculations easier but only i could try is $1 - \frac{X_{k+1}+X_{k+2}+X_{k+3}+...+X_{n}}{X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+...+X_{n}}$ and I am facing the same looking sum again,also can we use some trick as we know $E(X_{1}) = E(X_{i})$ for $i = 1,2,3,...,n$?

Also induction may help,i think.

Source: Problem 4.3-6 p. 126 of *An introduction to Probability and Statistics* by Rohatgi and Saleh.

Any help is great!

Comment: well..., you just have to find $E\Big(\dfrac{X_1}{X_1+\dots+X_n}\Big)$, I guess.

Comment: and that is $1/n$ .....I think.

Comment: so the answer should be $k/n$.... if I am doing right.

Comment: Yes,nice! but how are you getting the above expectation as $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: $E(\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{X_1+\dots+X_n})=\sum_i E(\frac{X_i}{X_1+\dots+X_n})$, now **you have to prove** here $E(X_1)=E(X_2)$ implies $ E(\frac{X_1}{X_1+\dots+X_n}) =E(\frac{X_2}{X_1+\dots+X_n})$, because of Exchangeable property.

Comment: The condition implying exchangeability is not $E(X_1)=E(X_2)$.

Comment: Is that $E(X_{1}) = E(X_{i}) $ for $i =2,3,4,...,n$@Did ?

Comment: What does exchageability tells you about the joint distribution of $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$? And the distributions of $\displaystyle f(X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots, X_n) =  \frac {X_1} {\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n X_j}$, $f(X_2, X_1, X_3, \ldots, X_n)$, and etc?

Comment: that they are identically distributed!

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420091/find-the-expectiation-of-displaystyle-fracx-1-dots-x-mx-1-dots-x/

Comment: @StubbornAtom the problem is, I think the solution in the link is for identical $X_i$'s. Is exchangeable and identical same here?

Comment: @MANMAID Exchangeability implies identical distribution but not necessarily independent.

Comment: @StubbornAtom is that Exchangeability implies identical distribution, or identical distribution implies Exchangeability?

Comment: Just to state that [Probability and Statistics chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65689/probability-and-statistics)

Comment: @MAN-MADE Someone really needs to check the **definition** of exchangeability here, if they want to stop making misleading noises.