# Finding expectation of random variable $ Y = \frac{A}{B} $

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Considering $X_1$, $X_2$ ,...., $X_{10}$ be independent and identically distributed positive random variables. How can I find expectation of  $$ Y = \frac{4 \cdot X_6 + 6 \cdot X_4}{\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i}  $$

I tried the following but stuck: 
$$ E(Y) = 4 \cdot E( \frac{X_6}{\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i}) + 6 \cdot E(\frac{X_4}{\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i}) $$

$$ E(Y) = 4 \cdot E( X_6) \ \cdot E( \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i}) + 6 \cdot E( X_4) \ \cdot E( \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i}) $$

How will I evaluate $$ E( \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i}) $$

Comment: You certainly cannot replace $$u_k=E\left(\frac{X_k}{X_1+\cdots+X_{10}}\right)$$ by $$E(X_k)E\left(\frac1{X_1+\cdots+X_{10}}\right)$$ since these are not independent. But, you might note that $$u_1+u_2+\cdots+u_{10}$$ is equal to $___$ and that by symmetry, $u_k$ and $u_\ell$ are $_______$, hence...

Comment: @Did each of $u_{i} = 1/10$ by symmetry ?

Comment: @BAYMAX Yes. $ $

Comment: Also related: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2420091/418542), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2430546/418542).