# Covariance of variables with Poisson and uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, covariance

Random variables $X_1, X_2,...,X_n,..$ are independent and have uniform distributions on $(0,1)$. Random variable $N$ has Poisson distribution with expected value $2$ and they are independent from $X_1,X_2,...,X_n,...$. 
Calculate $Cov\left(\frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} X_i },N\right)$.

I started from calculation of 
$E\left(\frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} X_i }N\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E\frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} X_i}\cdot k\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(N=k)}$.
I have a problem how to calculate 
$E\frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} X_i}$. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Condition on $N$ and use law of total expectation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expectation of random variables ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852890/expectation-of-random-variables-ratio)

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2420091

Comment: Thank you! I did it :)