# Value of $E\left[ \frac{X_1 +\cdots + X_k}{X_1 + \cdots + X_n} \right]$ if $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

> Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables. Calculate: $$E\left[ \frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_k}{x_1 + \cdots + x_n} \right]$$

I was wondering if I went about this the right way.
$$E \left[ \frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_k}{x_1 + \cdots + x_n} \right]$$
$$= \frac{E[x_1 + \cdots + x_k]}{E[x_1 + \cdots + x_n]}, \text{ since each is i.i.d } \implies $$
$$\frac{\mu_1 + \cdots + \mu_k}{\mu_1 + \cdots + \mu_n}$$
$$= \frac{k\mu}{n\mu} = \frac{k}{n}$$
$$= 0 \text{ if $k = n$ and }\frac{k}{n} \text{ if n > k}$$

Comment: Shouldn't your first displayed equation involve $n$?

Comment: That's right I typed that incorrectly

Comment: You wrote: "Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables." But then instead of $\displaystyle \operatorname E\left[ \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_k}{X_1+\cdots + X_n } \right]$ you wrote $\displaystyle \operatorname E\left[ \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_k}{x_1+\cdots + x_n }\right].$ That is not proper usage. If it is followed, how will one understand an expression like $\Pr(X\le x) \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Your last line, implying $k/n=0$ if $k= n$, is a mistake.

Comment: Question is incomplete; it should mention conditions for which $E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\right]$ exists. See the discussions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/852890/321264) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420091/find-expectation-of-fracx-1-cdots-x-mx-1-cdots-x-n-when-x-1-l?rq=1) for example. Did you mean to ask this same question?

Answer (score 2):

It is unfortunately not true that $E[X/Y]=E[X]/E[Y]$ even if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

However, we can show that 
$$\tag{*}
\mathbb E\left[\frac{X_j}{X_1+\dots+X_n}\right]=\mathbb E\left[\frac{X_1}{X_1+\dots+X_n}\right]=a.
$$
(this is due to the fact that $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and $(X_{\sigma(1)},\dots,X_{\sigma(n)})$, where $\sigma$ is a permutation, have the same law and $\sum_{i=1}^nX_{\sigma(i)}= \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

Also, note that $na=1$, by summing over $j$ in (*).

Comment: It is not instantly clear to me what distributions for $X_1$ are such that the expectations in (*)  exist.

Comment: @kimchilover The obvious ones are where $X_1 > 0$ a.s. or $X_1 < 0$ a.s.  That's not a necessary condition.  But on the other hand, if $X_1$ has a continuous density that is nonzero at some points $> 0$ and some points $< 0$, $X_1 + \ldots + X_n$ will have nonzero density at $0$ for some $n$.