# Show for all $\sigma \in S_n$ the distribution of $\mathbb{P}X \circ T{\sigma}^{-1}$ is equal

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

Let $\underline{Y}:=\left( Y_1,...,Y_n\right)$ be a vector with stochastic independent, identically distrubuted random variables with values in $\left\{1,2,3,...\right\}$ . For a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ , denote  $T_{\sigma}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ of the coordinates, so $T_{\sigma}(y_1,...,y_n):=(y_{\sigma}(1),...,y_{\sigma}(n))$

a)Show for all $\sigma \in S_n$ the distribution of $\mathbb{P}Y \circ T{\sigma}^{-1}$ is equal.

b) Argue that for every $1\leq i, j\leq n$ applies:

$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}\right)= \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_j}\right)$

c) Argue that for all $1\leq k \leq n$ applies:  $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i} \right)= \frac{k}{n}$

can someone please give me a tip for starting ?

Comment: (b) and (c) are almost entirely answered in comments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2420091/321264.