# Expectation of a specific ratio of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, variance, means

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^M$ be i.i.d. positive random variables, and let
$$
S_M = \frac1M \sum_{i=1}^M X_i,
$$
be the empirical mean of the sample. I am looking for an expression, or an upper bound, for the quantity
$$
\Phi = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac1M \sum_{i=1}^M \frac{X_i - S_M}{X_i}\right)^2\right].
$$

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852890/expectation-of-random-variables-ratio) is similar to what I'm asking, but I think my problem involves the variance of the difference.

Comment: I suspect you can do an expression in terms of the mean and variance of $X_i$ and $\frac{1}{X_i}$ but it will be messy

Comment: So for example, I suspect that if $X_i \sim U(0,1)$ then your $\Phi$ will be infinite

Comment: I suspect you might be right